# OSX Lion and VNC

Tags: macos, vnc, remote, osx-lion

I've recently been testing OSX Lion and I've been trying to use the multiuser VNC functionality. However, when I try logging in the TightVNC or COTVNC, I'm presented with a list of users (including the currently locally logged in user) but I'm unable to select a user to log in as (i.e. click on the user icon/name) has no effect. 
Are Apple forcing us to use ARD or must we be running Lion on the remote machine to log in too?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in their new implementation of features into VNC. I just tried with RealVNC viewer and Chicken of the VNC. Since it claims to be implementing VNC, I submitted a Radar, mirrored on OpenRadar.

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1204406

(I don't believe this is a violation of the NDA as I'm not revealing any new features.)

Also, you should check out AskDifferent.com, the Apple StackExchange. There's a lot more of "us" there than here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm hoping they'll fix this soon because it really puts a downer on the OS for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of the ARD protocol, as implemented in [Screen Sharing.app](http://www.macworld.com/article/161220/2011/07/lion_airdop_screen_sharing.html). I'm not sure that it's going to work in other VNC clients unless they use the ARD protocol (which I thought was proprietary.)